# how can fix this error " Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content. "

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, package, composer-php

**i recently installed laravel 5.8 for one of my projects but unfortunately i'v some problem in  installing packages that i have never had before..
for exp i want to install jrean package for verification users but i get this error :**

*Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Conclusion: don't install jrean/laravel-user-verification V8.0.0

- Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.8.35

- Installation request for jrean/laravel-user-verification ^8.0 -> satisfiable by jrean/laravel-user-verification[8.0.x-dev, V8.0.0].

- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- jrean/laravel-user-verification 8.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^6.0 -> satisfiable by
```

illuminate/support[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v

6.0.4].

```
- don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35

- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.8.35, required as 5.8.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.35].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.*

even i try this in my composer.json

"require": {
        "jrean/laravel-user-verification": "dev-master"
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that version 8.* requires Laravel 6.* as detailed in the versions table:

[image: versions table]

Since you're using Laravel 5.8 you should either install `jrean/laravel-user-verification@^7` or [update to Laravel 6.0](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade).

Comment: how i can be updated to laravel 6..i should start my project again?? and install laravel 6 or i can update it in php storm

Comment: If you don't need any features of version 8 I would just install version 7. Updating to Laravel 6 takes about an hour (or more depending on third-party packages). The [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade) explains how to upgrade.